# Asynchronous service proxy calls vertx

Tags: java, java-8, vert.x

I'm using service proxy library of vertx, and I'm having some trouble with the callback, my use case is :

Q1 --> Q2 ---->Q3, what I have done so far is :

```
 insertOrUpdate(query, client, updateBuildingNode -> {

            if (updateBuildingNode.succeeded()) {

                userService.getUserbyId(user, getUserRes -> {

                    User currentUser = Json.decodeValue(getUserRes.result().get(0).toString(), User.class);
                    userService.removeNodeFromUser(new JsonObject().put("user", new JsonObject(Json.encode(currentUser))).put("nodeUid", buildingUid), removeNodeFromUserRes -> {

                        if (removeNodeFromUserRes.succeeded()) {
                            if(currentUser.getFavoriteBuilding()!=null && currentUser.getFavoriteBuilding().equalsIgnoreCase(buildingUid)) {


                                userService.removeNodeAsFavorite(new JsonObject().put("userUid", userUid).put("nodeUid", buildingUid), resultHandler);

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(Boolean.TRUE));
                            }
                        } else {
                            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(removeNodeFromUserRes.cause()));
                        }
                    });


                });
            }
            else {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(updateBuildingNode.cause()));
            }

        });
```

My problem is that i want to do this calls like Q1 and Q2 wait for them to end and run Q3, and I have another request where I need to loop over Q[i] and wait for them all to them to do my logic.

I'm looking for something similar to angular js `$q.all(q1,q2)`

Any idea how can I do this in vertx and service proxy ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Async Coordination](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination) section in the docs. If you're often mixing different sources of events together you may also benefit from switching to the [Vert.x API for RxJava](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/).